# Differences between two regex

Tags: php, regex

I had this regex to fix corrupted serialized objects

```
$data = preg_replace(
    '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se',
    "'s:' . strlen('$2') . ':\"$2\";'", 
    $data
);
```

But recently updated the code for PHP 5.5+ because of  /e modifier has been deprecated

```
$data = preg_replace_callback(
    '/s:(\d+):"(.*?)";/', 
    create_function(
        '$matches', 
        'return "s:".strlen($matches[2]).":\"".( $matches[2] )."\";";'
    ),
    $data
);
```

I have analyzed the returning data of the both functions and it seems the new one is deletes additional slashes

result for 1

```
<a title=\\"A sample title\\" href=\\"http://sitei-url.com/\\">text</a>
```

result for 2

```
<a title=\"A sample title\" href=\"http://sitei-url.com/\">text</a>
```

when I try the `unserialize` the returning data, the first one is working ok but second one not

I'd appreciated to some help on this!

Thanks

**edit**

this one seems working as the first one. Added s parameter.

```
$data = preg_replace_callback(
    '/s:(\d+):"(.*?)";/s', 
    create_function(
        '$matches', 
        'return "s:".strlen($matches[2]).":\"".( $matches[2] )."\";";'
    ),
    $data
);
```

Thanks for everyone for their answers!

Comment: If the first one works, why don't use simply use it? what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The first one has the `s` modifier also, are you not using it on the second one?

Comment: Also show a example of input data please.

Comment: Change your `":\"".( $matches[2] )."\";"` to `":\\\"".( $matches[2] )."\\\";"`

Comment: @php-dev generates a syntax error, unexpected '"'

Comment: @PedroLobito the first one is not compatible with php 5.5 e modifier deprecated

Comment: @CBroe it is client's private data that's why i couldn't shared and can't reproduce the same one because it is too complicated and huge data

Comment: I don’t see much data that would require any “secrecy” in your example _output_, so I don’t see why you can not show matching input as well. _You_ want _our_ help, so give us something to work with.

Comment: You certainly changed the bad string. I recommend you to use a `closure` instead of `create_function`

Comment: @CBroe there is a big content that includes some pages that special for their paid customers only. I tried to change the content with some dummy text but it breaks the serialized data much worst. Believe me i can not share the data. 
How come the first one is working correctly but the second one is not. I'll be crazy.

Comment: @php-dev The Closure class requires PHP 5.3 > but i need to get it done with PHP 5.2.17 and at the same time must be compatible with php5.5, please don't ask why!! This is how they want..

Comment: I've replaced like this http://pastie.org/9163892

Comment: (facepalm) : You just said `But recently updated the code for PHP 5.5+ because of /e modifier has been deprecated`
This way I doubt you will get help ... Too many unargumented restrictions ...

Comment: @php-dev yes they want it working with php 5.2.17 and they have plans to update their server to PHP 5.5 in the future. That's why they're testing with both versions.

Answer (score 0):

An example with a `closure` :

```
$data = preg_replace_callback(
    '/s:(\d+):"(.*?)";/', 
    function($matches) { 
        return "s:" . strlen($matches[2]) . ":\\\"" . $matches[2] . "\\\";";
    ),
    $data
);
```

**EDIT For PHP 5.2 Compatibility**

```
function pregCallback($matches) {
    return "s:" . strlen($matches[2]) . ":\\\"" . $matches[2] . "\\\";";
}

$data = preg_replace_callback('/s:(\d+):"(.*?)";/', 'pregCallback', $data);
```

Comment: generates "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN" with PHP 5.2.17

Comment: the edited one replaces also the serialized data " with \" like s:15:\"display_widgets\";

Comment: orginal data `s:45:"<h1 style="text-align: center;">TEXT</h1>";`

must be looking like this `s:45:"<h1 style=\\"text-align: center;\\">TEXT</h1>";`

yours returns this `s:45:\"<h1 style=\\"text-align: center;\\">TEXTs</h1>\";`